# Angular lifecycle hook уходит в бесконечный цикл?

Tags: angular, angular4

В life cycle hook написал проверку, но по достижению переменной timer числа 10, хук уходит в бесконечный цикл вызовов в консоль числа 10, почему и как исправить?

```
ngDoCheck(): any {
    if (this.layoutService.timer == 10) {
      this.resetFilteringPanel();
      console.log(this.layoutService.timer)
    }
}
```

layoutService.ts:

```
      timer = 0;
    startTimer(): any {
    interval(1000).pipe(
    ).subscribe({
      next: count => {
        this.timer++;
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: не понимаю даже о  чем вы, однако вы в хуке явно изменяете некоторые значения компонента,  что вероятно приводит к рекурсии.

Comment: хочу сделать, так чтобы, когда переменная timer равна определенному числу, срабатывал метод resetFilteringPanel. Переменная увеличивается, каждую секунду бездействия пользователя, при любом действии равна 0.

Comment: А зачем тебе `ngDoCheck` для этого? :)

Comment: Так, а как можно решить эту проблему по-другому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно `ngDoCheck` используется для каких-то манипуляции с `ChangeDetectorRef` компонента (`detectChanges`, `attach` и тд). Это связано с тем, что хук триггерится в начале нового цикла проверки биндингов. Вы методом `this.resetFilteringPanel` наверняка меняете внутренние проперти, что триггерит очередной DoCheck и так по кругу.

Вероятно, в вашем случае правильнее будет просто подписаться на таймер `layoutService` в `ngOnInit` и в подписке проверять и манипулировать стейтом компонента.

```
// layout.service.ts
timer$ = interval(1000).pipe(share());

// ...component.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.layoutService.timer$
        .pipe(filter(n => n > 0 && n % 10 === 0))
        .subscribe(tick => this.resetFilteringPanel());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Да вы правы, в методе resetFilteringPanel делается запрос и меняются значения переменных. Подскажите, как правильно написать метод startTimer?

Comment: @gigabait1221 дополнил ответ